# Safari sort not the same as finder

Tags: finder, safari

When I pull up finder, files are sorted according to date:

[image: Finder sort]

But when I'm in Safari, and need to choose a file to upload, there's a bunch of files at the bottom of the picker that says "no date". This seems like a bug. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

[image: Safari file picker sort]

Comment: There are four different date fields that files can be sorted by.

Comment: Yeah, but no matter what sort I use, those "no date" files still show up under no date.

Comment: In fact, even if I remove all of the columns, the one remaining one - on the far left where it says "today" or "no date" remains (you can't edit or delete that one).  And the sort remains the same. In Finder, the files show up sorted correctly by date. When picking a file in Safari to upload, there's an increasing number of files that don't get sorted at all, and remain under the header "no date".

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested thoroughly yet, but the problem seems to happen for me when I leave Safari (11.1.2) open overnight. Quitting Safari and restarting it fixed the problem when I tried it today.

A similar bug has also been reported in Chrome ( https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=392754 ).  In that case restarting Chrome fixed the problem.

It feels to me as though the code providing the document picker is caching today's date for some reason and using that to compare the "Date Added" metadata to.  So it's more of an MacOS bug than a Safari bug.

Indeed if you look at the end of the thread here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3272875?start=45&tstart=0 there are several applications that show the same problem when left open overnight.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I didn't realize it, but you can actually click on the header (in Safari picker), and make more choices that way. So I did that, and chose "Date Created".  That fixed the sort problem.

[image: New sort]